# How to rebuild Qupzilla project

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

i am working on a open source Qupzilla which uses QT for frontend and C++ for back end.
i have build qupzilla from github source code.
i am actually trying to modify it according to my needs. when i make changes to source code. how to recompile it again.
i have followed same procedure as use for builiding initial project.
i used these commands .
1.qmake
2.make
3.sudo make install

but it does not make changes to browser shown. 
can anyone please suggest me way to recompile the project .

also  recompiling again from starting take lot of time , is there any short way .

Comment: make && make install in an existing build directory only recompiles (and re-links) what has been changed.

Comment: i am not clear with this as said by you, i used "make && make install" console message was 
make:  *** No rule to make target `instal'.  Stop.

Comment: You must run it in your existing build directory where you ran qmake before, when you built the last time.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld yes i did it in my build directory. but no change is reflected in UI.

Comment: Then you're not running what you built and installed, or qupzilla has build system issues. Get familiar with the process with some small example.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld i am in the same directory in which i installed qupzilla.
then i run make && make install .it shows some progress in building.
but changes are not reflected in actual application.
do i need to look anything else